# How to publish a directory from Joomla

Tags: joomla, configuration, joomla3.0, bitnami

I have a website created using joomla 3.0 (bitnami on amazon aws). I want to publish few files (html) from the website and was wondering how to do it ? Ideally I want to keep those htmls under /opt/bitnami/apps/joomla/htdocs/storage/matrix.html and then access it from my site using url : /storage/matrix.html

Any clues ?

Comment: Create a new menu item and set the type to "wrapper"

Comment: I think my question was not clear. I dont need to necessarily show those htmls in iframes on my site. What I want is to store htmls under the joomla installation so that any other application/user should be able to access those using a direct public url.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself after trying out a few things. What I did was created a new directory called storage under htdocs (of my joomla installation) and then also copied a htaccess.txt file inside it (from another public folder). And that's it ! This directory is now public and I can access it like I wanted !